# CSS: cannot position image in a specific location

Tags: html, css, position, background-image

I'm trying to position a background-image within a div element in the same line of a different block element (a video object), but it won't go up to align with the object. [Here's a screen shot of how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5l7v.jpg) (the cake banner at the bottom right won't go up).

Any help or insights on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

This is my **HTML** code of that section:

```
<div id="bottom">
   <div id=video>
       <h2>Weekly Inspiration Song</h2>
          <p>Every morning, as we get up and bake all the goodies for you, 
             we get inspired by great music!</p> 
          <p>We want to share our inspiration with you, so we will update 
            this section with our favorite inspiration song weekly.</p> 
      <p>We hope you enjoy it like we do!</p>
       <object data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ti7KWbicqcg" width="560" 
               height="315"></object>
       <br />
   </div>
   <div id="bottombanner">
     <a href="menu.htm"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my **CSS**:

```
div#video {
 width: 35%;
 margin-left: 1%
}


div#video h2 {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0px;
   font-family: 'StagSans-Book-Web',sans-serif;
}


div#video p {
   width: 560px; 
   font-size: 16px;
   font-family: 'StagSans-Book-Web',sans-serif;
}


div#video object {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
}


div#bottombanner a {
  background-image: url("cakebanner.jpg");
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: you should really read up on css4 grid, layout's shouldn't be botched

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/BJUfh This one screen grab sums it up I guess. Do you want me to type out a way of aligning it or do you want to try for yourself?

Comment: @SamApostel Thank you for that. I see where the problem is, and I've tried making this section smaller, but the right banner still won't align. If you could please type out a way of aligning it, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: remove the <br>

Comment: I appreciate all the help, guys! Removing the <br /> aligned the banner with the video indeed, but I wanted it aligned with the <h2>. I'm sorry I wasn't clear. @SamApostel

Comment: then put the `display: inline-block; float: left;` on the #video

Comment: @SamApostel Worked perfectly!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

to set both container side by side you may use display : `table`, `flex`, `grid` or `inline-block`.

*Also, mind your width (560px and 35% might not always match.*

- `flex`, the easiest :

```css
div#video {
  width: 35%;
  min-width:560px;
  margin-left: 1%
}

div#video h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'StagSans-Book-Web', sans-serif;
}

div#video p {
  width: 560px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'StagSans-Book-Web', sans-serif;
}

div#video object {
  float: left;
}

div#bottombanner a {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/500/nature");
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
}

/* for demo to avoid float to wrap */
#bottom {display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
  <div id=video>
    <h2>Weekly Inspiration Song</h2>
    <p>Every morning, as we get up and bake all the goodies for you, we get inspired by great music!</p>
    <p>We want to share our inspiration with you, so we will update this section with our favorite inspiration song weekly.</p>
    <p>We hope you enjoy it like we do!</p>
    <object data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ti7KWbicqcg" width="560" height="315"></object>

  </div>
  <div id="bottombanner">
    <a href="menu.htm"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

* `display:table/table-cell` *for older browsers such as IE8 ....*

```css
div#bottom {
  display: table;
}

div#video,
div#bottombanner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
}

div#video h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'StagSans-Book-Web', sans-serif;
}

div#video p {
  width: 560px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'StagSans-Book-Web', sans-serif;
}

div#video object {
  float: left;
}

div#bottombanner a {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/500/nature");
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
}


/* for demo to avoid float to wrap */

body {
  min-width: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
  <div id=video>
    <h2>Weekly Inspiration Song</h2>
    <p>Every morning, as we get up and bake all the goodies for you, we get inspired by great music!</p>
    <p>We want to share our inspiration with you, so we will update this section with our favorite inspiration song weekly.</p>
    <p>We hope you enjoy it like we do!</p>
    <object data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ti7KWbicqcg" width="560" height="315">
    </object>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="bottombanner">
    <a href="menu.htm"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

these are the two easiest and most css solid ways.

inline-block requires some extra tunning, grid is not well enough implemented yet, but will be so easy too to use.

---

About `float`, mind the [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) side effects when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

[http://imgur.com/a/BJUfh](https://imgur.com/a/BJUfh)

if you just delete the `<br>` it aligns perfectly ;p

Answer (score 0):

To start, I'd recommend that when you're debugging code you try right-click inspecting the elements. You can highlight over the DOM in the browser console and see the space the elements take up on the page. This will give you a good hint at where to start changing code.

Here are problems I noticed with your code:

1. You're floating the `object` left, which causes `#bottombanner` to jump up to the right, but you're not actually floating `#bottombanner` itself.
2. `#bottombanner` is not contained within the same parent as your `object`, which will make it very hard to do what you're trying to do without hacking things more than you really need to.

So the first thing we should do is move `#bottombanner` inside `#video`.

Then, kill the width on `#video` and have it just be `99%` wide (since it has a `1%` left margin). Take that `width: 35%` and apply it to your `object` instead.

Then, float both the `object` and `#bottombanner` to the left. With `object` at `width: 35%` and your container at `width: 99%`, that leaves `64%` for the width of `#bottombanner`.

Also, remove `display: inline-block` on your `object`. `display: inline-block` and `float: left` are contradictory statements; you cannot float an inline element.

Full code is below. I didn't include a stack snippet since it seems the YT video doesn't load in the snippet, so you can't really see the full effect that way anyway.

**HTML**

```
<div id="bottom">
  <div id=video>
    <h2>Weekly Inspiration Song</h2>
    <p>Every morning, as we get up and bake all the goodies for you, we get inspired by great music!</p>
    <p>We want to share our inspiration with you, so we will update this section with our favorite inspiration song weekly.</p>
    <p>We hope you enjoy it like we do!</p>
    <object data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ti7KWbicqcg" width="560" height="315"></object>
    <div id="bottombanner">
      <a href="menu.htm"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#video {
  /*width: 35%;*/
  margin-left: 1%
  width: 99%;
}
div#video h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'StagSans-Book-Web', sans-serif;
}
div#video p {
  width: 560px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'StagSans-Book-Web', sans-serif;
}
div#video object {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}
div#bottombanner {
  float: left;
  width: 64%;
}
div#bottombanner a {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/720x560");
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: @GCyrillus I know